# Django авторизация на домене и автоматически на субдомене

Tags: python, django

Есть сервер с 2 хостами. На одном домен, на другом субдомен и у каждого есть свой отдельный проект.
Оба проекта подключены к одной базе данных.
В настройках домена и субдомена SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'SSID'
В настройках домена SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.example.com'
Вхожу в админ. панель на домене, на субдомене не авторизовывается. Более того, вхожу в админ. панель на субдомене, выходит на домене.

Comment: решилось. Нужно было изменить секретные ключи на одинаковые.